# Read :id param from url as number in nodejs (Typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I need to get the :id param from url as number instead of string, to pass it on typeorm to fetch the data for particular id

here's how I am doing now. with this approach I have to write one more variable and manual conversion

```
router.get('/users/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const idNew: number = parseInt(id);
    
    userRepo.findOne({
        where: {id: idNew}
    })
})
```

Here's how I want to do (if possible)

```
router.get('/users/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    // maybe something like id as number

    userRepo.findOne({
        where: {id}
    })
})
```

Comment: `const id = ParseInt(req.params.id)`

Comment: @RinkeshP any way to convert string to number in typescript without parseInt?

Comment: Any reason to do that? You can write your own custom function which reads a string and returns an Integer, chances are its not going to be any better than `ParseInt`, much worse in fact.

Comment: You can coerce in TS with `as number`, but `id` is not a number, so it's a bad idea.

Comment: Why is the solution proposed in the first comment of @RinkeshP not working for you? You can declare `id` as type number now. No need for an extra variable.

Comment: Oky thanks, I was wondering if its possible in typescript using id as number.
Fortunately I found a way -> (id as unknown) as number

Answer (score 1):

You can fix both the TypeScript and runtime type error without a variable by inlining the `parseInt` call:

```
router.get('/users/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    
    userRepo.findOne({
        where: {id: parseInt(id)}
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce in TS with the `as` keyword

```
router.get('/users/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {  
    userRepo.findOne({
        where: {id: req.params.id as unknown as number}
    })
})
```

But you risk a database error if `req.params.id` cannot be cast to an integer in the resulting query. e.g.

> `QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "foo"`

Comment: I get this error : Conversion of type 'string' to type 'number' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
But this works -> (id as unknown) as number

Comment: As you can see, typescript is trying to tell you that this is a bad idea.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem since `re.params.id` is still a `string` at runtime. You got TypeScript to say that there are no type errors, but there's still going to be a runtime type error.

Comment: The question is asking how to pass a `number`, not how to fix the TypeScript error.